# Как правильнее хранить данные в базе Postgres

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, структуры-данных

Как правильно хранить данные в базе Postgres? У меня есть 10 книг (внутри книги текст, формат файла txt), каждая по 10 мб. Вижу 2 варианта хранения этих данных.

Первый - это хранить так: все файлы в одной общей таблице, где одна книга - это одна ячейка, которая увеличивается по мере увеличения размера файла. (1 книга - это 1 ячейка или одинарная строчка). Смысл: при этом подходе мы получим 10 строчек, где каждая строчка ссылается на одну книгу. (Этакое увеличение одной ячейке, которое зависит от размера файла). При нем у меня данные в ячейке обрезаются, и большая часть текста храниться, где-то в таблице TOAST. Я могу увидеть первые 2-3 слова и все.
(Создавал индекс gin для столбца (Текст из файла), при таком подходе он работает 1-2 сек)

Второй - это ситуация, когда мы храним каждый файл в отдельной таблице. Внутри этой таблицы одна колонка, в которой и располагаются данные. Тем самым мы получаем таблицу, с одним столбом, в котором сколько-то строчек. Таких таблиц 10. Смысл: одна таблица ссылается на одну книгу. (Этакое увеличение Кол-ва строчек, оно зависит от размера файла, при этом это похоже на увеличения вглубь таблицы).
(При таком методе, думаю создать для каждой таблицы свой индекс gin)

Подскажите, что лучше использовать при полнотекстовом поиске. Пока у меня есть одна общая таблица в которой 10 строчек и 3 столбца (ID, Имя файла, Текст из файла). Операция headline при таком случае выполняется 20 сек. Думаю перейти на 2 способ (который описан выше). Сделал пока 2 таблицы. Каждая ссылается на одну смысловую единицу, на свою книгу. При таком подходе headline выполняется 100мс.

Вопрос: подскажите как лучше организовать базу данных? Как лучше в ней хранить текстовые данные? Какие типы колонок использовать (у меня пока для текста тип character varying).

Comment: Индекс для полнотекстового поиска добавляли?

Comment: Да, для столбца (Текст из файла) создавал gin индекс. Он загружает 1-2 сек.

Comment: Так же проверял в (Explain analyze), и увидел, что индекс используется. Сканер- Bitmap Heap Scan.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, какие запросы вы выполняете в двух случаях. Вы сравниваете запрос, который возвращает данные для *всех* книг (1-2 секунды) с запросом для одной книги (100 мс)? В общем случае, нет особой причины, по которой индивидуальные запросы, возвращающие те же данные будут быстрее чем один, который сразу возвращает все, должно быть наоборот (разве что серверу очень не хватает ресурсов). Если у вас получается так, то нужно смотреть причину такого поведения.

Comment: Я стараюсь понять как лучше положить данные в базу, чтобы было быстрее. Один общий запрос ( рассматривая 10 книг) или же 10 единичных запросов (1 запрос на одну книгу), которые внутри qt будут рассматривать все книги и выдавать результат постепенно, а не весь как при общим запросе.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, при моем первом случае, (когда один общий запрос), он выполняется долго если будет headline, зато если делать много единичных запросов ( c headline), то в сумме время все равно будет меньше.
Может есть какие-то мысли как лучше именно хранить данные?